# How to fill a 2d array with different types of variables in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to make an array in which i could place different types of variables depending on what the case may be, how would i go about doing that? ive tried to code something myself but when i try to compile it i still get an error saying i cannot convert say int to data, this is my method:

```
private static Data[][] set(Scanner sc, int grid, int collumn) {
    Data[][] data = new Data[collumn][];
    for (int i = 0; i < collumn; i++) {
        switch(sc.nextInt()) {
            case 0:
                data[i] = new int[grid];
            case 1:
                data[i] = new String[grid];
            case 2: 
                data[i] = new boolean[grid];
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

I do have a Data class, however it is empty, and i read grid and collumn just at the beginning of my main method, which is also empty besides the 2 scanner lines, would i have to write anything specific in the Data class?

Here is my complete code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class dn11 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    grid = sc.nextInt();
    collumn = sc.nextInt();
    set(sc, grid, collumn);

  }


private static Data[][] set(Scanner sc, int grid, int collumn) {
    Data[][] data = new Data[collumn][];
    for (int i = 0; i < collumn; i++) {
        switch(sc.nextInt()) {
            case 0:
                data[i] = new int[grid];
            case 1:
                data[i] = new String[grid];
            case 2: 
                data[i] = new boolean[grid];
        }
    }
    return data;
}



private static abstract class Data extends dn11 {

}
```

}

Comment: Why not use an `Array` of `String`, and then convert it, the way suits the needs? Or store everythingy as `Object` and typecast as needed.

Comment: It would help us if you post your complete code

Comment: Cow how would i go about doing that? Sorry im kind of a beginner

Comment: This is a 3D array, not a 2D one.

Comment: Could you please post the data you want to read into the array? Maybe it's best to use an Object[][]. This stores a table of 'something'.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can only do this:

```
     data[i] = new data[grid];
```

because data array can contain only objects of type data.

you can put 3 attributes inside this class as:

```
    int i;
    String s;
    Boolean b;
```

and 1 more attribute to keep track of whether its int or String or Boolean is valid
For example

```
   int val;
```

now if val is 1 then String should contain its value, if val is 2 then int contains the value.

The variable val can be initialized in constructor.

Comment: How would i then write the constructor?

Comment: Data(int a){ val =a;} // a=1 for int. a =2 for string.

Comment: To call the constructor you'll be doing this. data[i] = new Data[grid];   for(int j=0;j<grid;j++) { data[i][j] = new data(a);         }

Answer (score 1):

My example of how to store 'something' into an array:

```
class dn11 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows = 5;
        int cols = 5;
        Object[][] data = new Object[rows][cols];
        data[2][4] = "content of 2-4"; //stores a String
        data[3][1] = 3.14; //stores a double
        data[0][0] = 100; //stores an int

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                System.out.print(data[row][col] + " / ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This prints the following:

> 100 / null / null / null / null / 
>   null / null / null / null / null /
>  
>   null / null / null / null / content of 2-4 / 
>   null / 3.14 / null / null / null / 
>   null / null / null / null / null /

null means that in that cell is stored nothing.

Comment: The data i have to post is interchangable tho, it may be 4 collums on ints, may be 1 int 2 strings and a boolean, it may be 2 ints 2 strings

Comment: If the data contains always 4 values (of whatever type) this would work perfect. If the size of the data changes you should think about using ArrayList<Object> or other stuff out of the java collections.